# Roundabout jquery in document Strict

Tags: jquery, strict

I am useing Roundabout jquery at: http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/ in document Strict, but it dont woking in IE.
This is my source:

HTML:

```
<ul class="roundabout">
    <li><a title="#" href="#"><img alt="product 1" src="images/product-1.gif" /></a></li>
    <li><a title="#" href="#"><img alt="product 2" src="images/product-2.gif" /></a></li>
    <li><a title="#" href="#"><img alt="product 3" src="images/product-3.gif" /></a></li>
    <li><a title="#" href="#"><img alt="product 4" src="images/product-4.gif" /></a></li>
    <li><a title="#" href="#"><img alt="product 5" src="images/product-5.gif" /></a></li>
    <li><a title="#" href="#"><img alt="product 6" src="images/product-6.gif" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.roundabout-holder { height:250px; list-style:none; margin:0 auto; margin-bottom:50px; width:90%; }
.roundabout-moveable-item { height:190px; width:95px; }
.roundabout-moveable-item a { cursor:move; }
.roundabout-in-focus {}
.roundabout-in-focus a { cursor:pointer; }
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".roundabout").roundabout({
        easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
        shape: 'lazySusan'
    })
    .hover(
        function() {
            clearInterval(interval);
        },
        function() {
            interval = startAutoPlay();
        }
    );

    interval = startAutoPlay();

    function startAutoPlay() {
        return setInterval(function() {
            jQuery(".roundabout").roundabout_animateToNextChild();
            }, 3000);
    }
});
```

Why is it? and How to i fix it IN DOCUMENT STRICT, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try it with

Css:

```
.roundabout-moveable-item img { height:100%: width:100%; }
```